# How to change ForeignKey value using inlineformset?

Tags: python, django

I have two models and forms linked by the ForeignKey 'squad'. In my templates I have the user first typing the Squad name and then the shooters. I am trying to hardcode the 'squad' field of my Shooters with the 'squad_name' of my ShooterSquad so the user doesn't have to type the squad name every time for every shooter.

**models.py**

```
class ShooterSquad(models.Model):
    squad_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.squad_name

class Shooter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    squad = models.ForeignKey(ShooterSquad, to_field='squad_name', related_name='squad', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class ShooterSquadForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ShooterSquad
    fields = ['squad_name', 'squad_total_score', ]

class ShooterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shooter
        fields = '__all__'

class BaseShooterFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseShooterFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.queryset = Shooter.objects.none()

ShooterFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ShooterSquad, Shooter,
    form=ShooterForm,
    formset=BaseShooterFormSet,
    extra=1,
    max_num=3,
    exclude=('squad',)
)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_multiple_shooters(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    squad_form = ShooterSquadForm(request.POST)
    formset = ShooterFormSet(request.POST)
    if squad_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        set_squad = squad_form.cleaned_data.get('squad_name')
        for f in formset.forms:
            f.cleaned_data['squad_id'] = set_squad
            f.cleaned_data['squad'] = set_squad
            print(formset.cleaned_data)
        squad_form.save()
        formset.save()
        return redirect('anasp:mainpage')
else:
    print("ERROR")
    formset = ShooterFormSet()
    squad_form = ShooterSquadForm()
context = {
    "title": title,
    "formset": formset,
    "squad_form": squad_form,
}
return render(request, "anasp/scores/shooter_formset.html", context)
```

[Input Form Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsjDs.png)

My cleaned_data prints: `[{'shooter_number': 67, 'squad': 'Woodland', 'name': 'Legolas', 'DELETE': False, 'id': None, 'shooter_score': 39, 'squad_id': 'Woodland'}]`

So it seems that the squad_id has changed right? Wrong. When I look in my db my squad_id is `<null>`
How do I fix that?

Python: 3.5.4  Django: 1.8

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by not committing the save before all the changes were made:

```
    if squad_form.is_valid():
        squad = squad_form.save(commit=False)

        if formset.is_valid():
            shooters_to_save = list()

            for f in formset.forms:
                shooter = f.save(commit=False)
                shooter.squad = squad
                shooters_to_save.append(shooter)

            squad.save()

            for shooter in shooters_to_save:
                shooter.save()
            return redirect('anasp:mainpage')
```